# Kivymd ListItems text size

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to change the font size of kivymd List Items.

Is there a way to change **font_size** of kivymd List Items. Be it OneLineListItems or any List item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text="[size=54]Discard draft?[/size]"`